# Why does the value stored in a register change after an x/s call? (GDB)

Tags: gdb

I have run the following commands at a breakpoint in gdb and I don't understand how the x/d $rdx commands returns two different values, one before and one after x/s $rdx is executed. To my understanding x is just for reading values?

```
(gdb) x/d $rdx
0x555555559180: -6681
(gdb) x/s $rdx
0x555555559180: "\347\345\377\377\221\345\377\377\261\345\377\377\270\345\377\377\277\345\377\377\306\345\377\377\315\345\377\377\324\345\377\377\002"
(gdb) x/d $rdx
0x555555559180: -25
```

I guess it's more likely I'm misunderstanding something in terms of the x command and how it works so any info on that would be really helpful.

Comment: This is a secondary issue, but `x $rdx` reads from the memory address pointed to by `rdx`. To read the value stored in `rdx` as decimal use gdb's `print` command: `p/d $rdx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x/d` reads the value starting at some address and display it as decimal.

If you don't specify a size, `x` will use the default or the last size used.

Your first `x/d` reads the default size - a word (typically 4-bytes).

Then `x/s` reads a string, that is *1* string.

The last `x/d` then reads one byte, as *1* was the last size used.

To avoid this, specify a size for the command:

For example:
`x/wd` will read a word-sized value as decimal and `x/bx` will read one byte value as hex.

Numeric notation is also accepted:

`x/8bx` will read 8 bytes as hex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!